# bcrypt cost 1 blank hash?

Tags: bcrypt, crypt

i want the crypt-formatted bcrypt hash for a blank password with cost 1, but the api i'm using to hash these passwords refuse to generate a hash with a cost below 4 (for obvious reasons), what does a cost 1 password look like?

for completeness, here's a blank password with the salt being 22x `A` with cost 4, it's the closest i've got so far: `$2a$04$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.lvvkzzqrMPdnab8Xxl8zf7j6C1s84c6`

and that was generated with the php code `crypt("",'$2a$04$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')` (but php refuse to create hashes below cost 4)

Answer (score 0):

for password=(emptystring) cost=1 and salt=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA the hash is:

```
$2a$01$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.9/Ai1w9JdKxud1gCb2hYi1hHz9IYr0m
```

it's also possible to use 0 iterations, in which the hash is

```
$2a$00$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.xQIqw.yJbZDA8V.ef0psIHmBBBaQfhy
```

here is output from a modified php where the minimum cost is removed:

```
root@x2ratma:/temp/php-src# sapi/cli/php -r 'var_dump(crypt("",'\''$2a$04$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'\''));'
string(60) "$2a$04$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.lvvkzzqrMPdnab8Xxl8zf7j6C1s84c6"
root@x2ratma:/temp/php-src# sapi/cli/php -r 'var_dump(crypt("",'\''$2a$03$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'\''));'
string(60) "$2a$03$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.TCFhOtNOtk2Oeef1z4xP561tW1AQOMW"
root@x2ratma:/temp/php-src# sapi/cli/php -r 'var_dump(crypt("",'\''$2a$02$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'\''));'
string(60) "$2a$02$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.C43gUGAZorcHKVYot1kaRPwCYWt2Ehm"
root@x2ratma:/temp/php-src# sapi/cli/php -r 'var_dump(crypt("",'\''$2a$01$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'\''));'
string(60) "$2a$01$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.9/Ai1w9JdKxud1gCb2hYi1hHz9IYr0m"
root@x2ratma:/temp/php-src# sapi/cli/php -r 'var_dump(crypt("",'\''$2a$00$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'\''));'
string(60) "$2a$00$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.xQIqw.yJbZDA8V.ef0psIHmBBBaQfhy"
```

the changes made to php-src was:

```
root@x2ratma:/temp/php-src# git diff --patch
diff --git a/ext/standard/crypt_blowfish.c b/ext/standard/crypt_blowfish.c
index 3806a290ae..f72cfb51df 100644
--- a/ext/standard/crypt_blowfish.c
+++ b/ext/standard/crypt_blowfish.c
@@ -647,7 +647,7 @@ static const unsigned char flags_by_subtype[26] =
 static char *BF_crypt(const char *key, const char *setting,
        char *output, int size,
        BF_word min)
-{
+{min=0;
        struct {
                BF_ctx ctx;
                BF_key expanded_key;
diff --git a/ext/standard/password.c b/ext/standard/password.c
index a19266d214..3c7e1d6926 100644
--- a/ext/standard/password.c
+++ b/ext/standard/password.c
@@ -192,7 +192,7 @@ static zend_string* php_password_bcrypt_hash(const zend_string *password, zend_a
                cost = zval_get_long(zcost);
        }

-       if (cost < 4 || cost > 31) {
+       if (cost < 0 || cost > 31) {
                zend_value_error("Invalid bcrypt cost parameter specified: " ZEND_LONG_FMT, cost);
                return NULL;
        }
```

... unfortunately php's password_verify() (incorrectly?) returns bool(false) for hashes below cost 4...